# ¿Cómo realizo la siguiente consulta cUrl en php? (application/x-www-form-urlencoded)

Tags: php, api, curl, sql

La consulta ha realizar es la siguiente:

> POST https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer
>   HTTP/1.1
>
> Accept: application/json
>
> Authorization: Basic UTM0dVBvRDIwanp2OUdxNXE1dmlMemppcTlwM1d2
>       NzRUdDNReGkwZVNTTDhFRWwxb0g6VEh0WEJlR3dheEtZSlVNaFhzeGxma1l
>       XaFg3ZlFlRzFtN2szTFRwbw==
>
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
>
> Host: oauth.platform.intuit.com
>
> Body: grant_type=authorization_code&
>         code=L3114709614564VSU8JSEiPkXx1xhV8D9mv4xbv6sZJycibMUI&
>         redirect_uri=https://www.mydemoapp.com/oauth-redirect

Se como iniciar curl y ejecutarlo, pero presiento que tengo algún detalle en el header o el body. json_encode() quizá? o debo construir la url del "body"

```
<?php 

session_start();

$state = $_GET['state'];

if( $state == $_SESSION['token_sess']):

    $realmId = $_GET['realmId'];
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    $_SESSION['realmId'] = $realmId;

    // Setting the authorization header

    $client_id = "clientIdproporsionada";
    $client_secret = "clientSecretProposrionada";
    $Authorization = "Basic " . base64_encode($client_id . ":" . $client_secret);

    $http_header = array(
        'Accept' => 'application/json',
        'Authorization' => $Authorization,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Host' => 'oauth.platform.intuit.com'
    );

    $body = array(
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'code' => trim($code),
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://localhost/intuit/someaddress.php?oauth-redirect'
    );

    $payload = json_encode($body);

    //API URL
    $url = 'https://oauth.platform.intuit.com/oauth2/v1/tokens/bearer';

    $headers_req = array();

    foreach($http_header as $k => $v){
        $headers_req[] = $k . ":" . $v;
    }

    //create a new cURL resource
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers_req,
        CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $payload
    ));

    if( !$result = curl_exec($ch) ){
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($ch) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($ch));
        curl_close($ch);
    } else{
        var_dump(json_encode($result));
        curl_close($ch);
    }







else:

    echo "something wrong";

endif;
```

La respuesta que recibo del servidor es

> string(400) ""HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request\r\nContent-Type:
>   application/json;charset=UTF-8\r\nContent-Length: 27\r\nConnection:
>   keep-alive\r\nKeep-Alive: timeout=5\r\nServer: nginx\r\nDate: Thu, 26
>   Apr 2018 19:02:16 GMT\r\nStrict-Transport-Security:
>   max-age=15552000\r\nintuit_tid:
>   xxxxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-xxx\r\nCache-Control: no-cache,
>   no-store\r\nPragma: no-cache\r\n\r\n{\"error\":\"invalid_request\"}""

De antemano, agradecido!!

Comment: No hace falta que conviertas a JSON el arreglo ni que lo pongas en el body. Pasalo directo a curl y este se encarga de armar la consulta. Además no deberías poner el token que usas para autenticarte en un lugar público...

Comment: Gracias Roberto Vaccaro, ya estaba posteando la misma solución y en efecto no se debe usar json en la variable sino pasar directo la url con los datos que solicita. Los datos tales como Authorization y Code acá mostrados son genéricos, tomados de la misma documentación del sitio de la Api, es decir no son válidos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No hace falta que conviertas a JSON el arreglo ni que lo pongas en el body. Pasalo directo a curl y este se encarga de armar la consulta.

```
$body = array(
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
        'code' => trim($code),
        'redirect_uri' => 'https://localhost/intuit/someaddress.php?oauth-redirect'
);

curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => TRUE,
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers_req,
    CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'POST',
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $body <--
));
```

El formato de los datos que tenés que enviar está definido por la cabecera *Content-Type* y en este caso es *application/x-www-form-urlencoded*.

Es decir tendrías que pasar un string del formato *param1=value1&param2=value...* pero si pasás un arreglo a curl, este automáticamente se encarga de hacer la conversión.